# Extract specific information directly from Visio file in c#

Tags: c#, visio

I want to fetch the following 5 elements of reporting information directly from a visio document in c#:

1. Page name
2. Shape name
3. X and Y coordinates of each shape
4. Height and width of each shape
5. Displayed text

I can export this data to an excel file using report in visio and then fetch it from there in c# code. **But** it will be most convenient to get it directly from the visio document. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you type "google c# visio file format" at all ? The first hit I got was the helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622.aspx which describes in full how to program C# against the Visio file format.

Comment: @PhillipH Sachin didn't specify which visio format was relevant, but that hit only applies to the OpenXML-based formats e.g .vsdx

Comment: @Emyr - correct, its for the OpenXML format (the default from Visio 2012 onwards I think).